# How can I access the individual values my nested python list below? Whats the Best way to loop over my list to get them?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

I am at a loss as to how I can iterate over each value in the list below. For instance I want to print the "names" only, how would I do that ?

The list:

```
List = [{
'name': ['NARUTO×UT', 'Naruto, the Genie, and the Three Wishes, Believe It!', 'Naruto SD: Rock Lee no Seishun Full-Power Ninden Mō Iccho', 'Naruto Shippūden: The Burning Chūnin Exam! Naruto vs. Konohamaru!!', 'Naruto: The Cross Roads', 'Naruto Spin-Off: Rock Lee & His Ninja Pals', 'Naruto Shippūden: Shippū! "Konoha Gakuen" Den', 'Naruto Shippūden: Blood Prison', 'Naruto Shippūden: The Lost Tower', 'Naruto Shippūden: The Will of Fire', 'Naruto Shippūden the Movie: Bonds', 'Naruto Shippūden', 'Naruto: Konoha Sports Festival', 'Naruto Shippūden', 'Naruto the Movie: Guardians of the Crescent Moon Kingdom', 'Naruto', 'Naruto the Movie: Legend of the Stone of Gelel', 'Naruto Special: Battle at Hidden Falls. I Am the Hero!', 'Naruto: Akaki Yotsuba no Clover o Sagase', 'Naruto the Movie: Ninja Clash in the Land of Snow', 'Naruto'],     
'poster': ["flyer 1","flyer 2", "flyer 3", "flyer 4", "flyer 5","flyer 6" "flyer 7", "flyer 8", "flyer 9", "flyer 10", "flyer 11", "flyer 12", "flyer 13", "flyer 14"],     
'summary': ["plot 1", "plot 2", "plot 3", "plot 4", "plot 5", "plot 6", "plot 7", "plot 8","plot 9", "plot 10", "plot 11", "plot 12","plot 13", "plot 14", ]
}]
```

The best way I can think of is to try using a nested for loop to get access for all the "name" values only but I get:

> "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

I want to be able to pass my LIST to my HTML page and display the values there  for "name" "poster" and "summary" there.

```
for anime in list:
    for show in anime:
        print(show["name"])
```

Comment: You don't need a nested loop. Just `print(anime['name'])`

Comment: You say you want to iterate over each value in the list, but your list contains only one value - a dictionary with three items.

Comment: Your data design seems wrong. You should have a list of dictionaries, and each dictionary should just have one name, poster, and summary.

Comment: `List[0]['name']` will give you list of only names

Comment: @Barmar I actually got my list from a xml parse. and then placed it into the list.

Comment: Maybe you should fix that code to organize it better.

Comment: @Barmar working on that, will update my question based on your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the data inside the List, after carefully examining the data, you miss a " sign in flyer 9

You literally create a dictionary in your List[0], you can pass the List [0] to a new dictionary

```
newDictionary = dict(List[0])
```

then you can access the names by using get method

```
print(newDictionary.get("name"))
```

or just convert that list into a dictionary

Comment: Since `List[0]` is already a dictionary, there's no need to call `dict()`.